# Generating files of varying variability?

Tags: files, compression, random

I have used `/dev/zero` and `/dev/random` to generate files of certain size.
However, is there a way to control variability of generated files?

I would like to create few files that would have same uncompressed size, but different compressed size (compression ratio).

Comment: Only use `/dev/random` if you want to generate cryptagraphic keys as it may block when the entropy pool is exhausted. For normal operations like file generation use `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: @ThomasErker And [if you want to generate cryptographic keys, use `/dev/urandom` as well](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939).

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'abcd' | dd count=10 bs=1 2>/dev/null
```

generates 10 bytes of (pseudo-)random sequence out of a, b, c, and d. Modify the alphabet (here "abcd") to get other compression rates.